# Google BigQuery Permissions Issue stopping scheduled queries from running

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We had a data intern who scheduled a lot of queries to power our google data studio reports. After she left, we removed her access, and now the queries don't run.

This is the error we see:

> BigQuery error: Access Denied: Table pm-match-mobile:analytics_232872718.DAU_WAU_MAU: Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table pm-match-mobile:analytics_232872718.DAU_WAU_MAU (or it may not exist).

Is there a way to transfer access or ownership of those queries to a different email/account so that we don't have to do everything from scratch as it will cost us a ton of time?

Comment: Are you getting this error from Data Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use scheduled queries, but [the manual says that the credentials for scheduled queries can be changed by clicking in the console or via the API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#console_3).

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in the DataStudio I would suggest reassigning Data credentials in the Data Srouce of this report to a different user:

1. Open the report
2. Resource -> Manage added data sources -> Edit the relevant data source
3. On the top you will see "Data credentials" - update this with the user that has the required access to BigQuery (or whatever data source in use)